# Why does file_put_contents not work in my online php script?

Tags: javascript, php, file-put-contents

I am trying to use a .php file to edit a .txt file on my http web server. I can call the .php file and get it to run (and echo something random back) just fine, but when I use file_put_contents it doesn't work. I have tried setting file permissions to 777, 0775, etc but nothing happens. (although from what I have gathered, it seems that permissions are for local systems only). I know that there are some similar questions already here, but I cannot understand the answers to any of them.

testingPHP.js (trimmed):

```js
function submitData() {
    var data = prompt('Enter data');
    sendToServer(data, 'test.txt');
}

function sendToServer(data, file) {//file is file to write into, not the php file
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "editTXT.php?txtFile=file&data=data");
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout(update, 500);
}

function update() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = xhttp.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "readTxt.php?file=test.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

editTxt.php:

```php
<?php
$txtFile = $_GET["txtFile"];
$data = $_GET["data"];
file_put_contents($txtFile, $data);
?>
```

readTxt.php:

```php
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$data = file_get_contents($file);
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: What is the output out of the CLI command ```getenforce``` on your server?

Comment: in `editTxt.php` can you confirm ( `file_exists` etc ) that the file does exist?!

Comment: I have done some fixing now, and file_exists() says true

Comment: and has that helped fix the issue or still unable to write to the textfile?

Comment: Also: I have no idea how to enter a CLI command and can't find any relevant pages on the web.

Comment: It still doesn't work after checking with file_exists()

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following might help - I think the main problem is in the javascript funnily enough but I'll post here the changes I made to all files anyway. Incidentally - constant polling like this using Ajax could instead be done in a cleaner way using an EventSource connection and Server Sent Events.

If the textfile is to be overwritten completely when the script is invoked then this works fine ( in test anyway ) but if the data is intended to add to existing content you'd need to add `FILE_APPEND` as the final argument to `file_put_contents`

**editTxt.php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['txtFile'], $_GET['data'] ) ){

        $file=__DIR__ . '/' . $_GET['txtFile'];
        $data=$_GET['data'];

        $bytes=file_put_contents( $file, $data );
        if( !$bytes )exit('error');

    }
?>
```

**readTxt.php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['file'] ) ){
        $file=__DIR__ . '/' . $_GET['file'];
        exit( file_get_contents( $file ) );
    }
?>
```

And the HTML & Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function submitData() {
                var data = prompt('Enter data');

                if( data ){/* only submit if there is data */
                    sendToServer(data, 'test.txt');
                    setInterval(update, 1000);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function sendToServer(data, file) {//file is file to write into, not the php file
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    }
                }
                /* the filename and the data need to be escaped in the string */
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "editTXT.php?txtFile="+file+"&data="+data);
                xmlhttp.send();
                setTimeout(update, 500);
            }

            function update() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var response = xhttp.responseText;
                    console.log(response);
                }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "readTxt.php?file=test.txt", true);
                xhttp.send();
            }


            /* call the function that prompts for data input */
            submitData();       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am going to try your solution

Comment: I've copied your changes into all files but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at the apache error log? I assume it is apache but it might not be ...

Comment: I will try that when I have some time

Comment: ok - the above worked fine for me in testing though I've modified it since.

Comment: The problem may be because I have a web server with my internet provider - they give me 1GB of space that I can upload to using FTP

Comment: The fact that you can upload/download to and from your webserver via ftp is unrelated to this issue. Permissions on the working directory are important as is knowing the correct path.